# Conditional lookahead for preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have the following code to extract javascript code:

```
preg_match_all('#<script(?:[^>]+)?>(.*?)</script>#is', $GLOBALS['content'], $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)
```

It works excellent for this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="application/javascript">
<script>
```

But how do I avoid matching?

`<script type="application/ld+json">`

Comment: With `'#<script(?![^>]*\stype="application/ld+json")[^>]*>(.*?)</script>#is'`

Comment: Are you *just* looking to match Javascript?

Comment: Yes, only javasscript.

Comment: Perhaps a reverse condition would be best? If parameter type is not set or set to text/javascript or application/javascript.

Comment: Only matching javascripts #<script(?:[^>]*\stype="(?:application|text)/javascript")?[^>]*>(.*?)</script>#is

Comment: The plus sign should have been escaped for sure, I typed in a very  uncomfortable position :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either as @Wiktor says (using a negative lookahead) or with a parser:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
<script type="text/javascript">some js code here</script>
<script type="application/javascript">some other code here</script>
<script>This looks naked, dude!</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">THIS MUST NOT BE MATCHED</script>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$scripts = $xpath->query("//script[not(@type='application/ld+json')]");
foreach ($scripts as $script) {
    # code...
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
<script(?!\stype="application\/ld\+json")[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>
```

It uses negative lookahead to exclude the unwanted JSON. You might not need to escape the backslashes. But you need to escape the **+** sign in **ld+json** to prevent it from being treated as a quantifier rather than verbatim.

See it in action: [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/kR1vY6/1)

Please comment if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Answer (score 0):

Opposite of the solution by @Wiktor, to match any javascript...

```
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
<script type="application/javascript">...</script>
<script>...</script>
```

...and skip any other types, use:

```
 #<script(?:[^>]*\stype="(?:application|text)/javascript")?[^>]*>(.*?)</script>#i‌​s
```